# Library to generate pcap-file from application logs

Tags: c#, pcap

I have been looking at generation pcap-files myself, from application log-files. (I figured that Wireshark would be a good tool for analyzing how network traffic has bounced around in the system.)

However, the believed simple task seems hard. I have the network data (SIP-data in my case). I should then wrap this data with IP+UDP header and also the [pcap-headers](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat). This seemed easy, but somehow I just fail. When I open the pcap in Wireshark all headers are just mushed.

If I give up, is there a library I can use to do the writing of pcap files?
(All libraries I have find seem to focus on captioning from device to file. I dont have a device here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a managed library called [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page), which is a wrapper around libpcap, to interface with pcap files. Using that library you should be cable of both reading and 'capturing' packets. The classes/functions of interest would be 
[CaptureFileWriterDevice](http://sharppcap.sourceforge.net/htmldocs/SharpPcap.LibPcap/CaptureFileWriterDevice.html) and perform [SendPacket](http://sharppcap.sourceforge.net/htmldocs/SharpPcap.LibPcap/PcapDevice.html#M%3aSharpPcap.LibPcap.PcapDevice.SendPacket%28System.Byte%5b%5d,System.Int32%29) or alternatively [Write](http://sharppcap.sourceforge.net/htmldocs/SharpPcap.LibPcap/CaptureFileWriterDevice.html#M%3aSharpPcap.LibPcap.CaptureFileWriterDevice.Write%28SharpPcap.RawCapture%29) operations for each packet you want to record.

Comment: Here is a more detailed description of how I finally solved the issue.
http://bitlearn.blogspot.se/2012/06/at-work-we-have-our-telephony.html